# Basic Form react

Tags: reactjs, forms

Hello I just want to make a form and my textboxes does not take my inputs and my submit works but sends no values. What am I doing wrong? I know it's a basic question but I don't know what the problem is in my code.

Key problems:

1. it doesn't update the state nor take my inputs.
2. fields editable but cant write into them

Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Postform extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      category: "",
      price: "",
    };
  }

  changeHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState = { [e.target.name]: e.target.value }; 
  };

  submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
  
    const { name, category, price } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              placeholder="Name"
              value={name}
              onChange={this.changeHandler}
            />

            <input
              type="text"
              name="category"
              placeholder="Category"
              value={category}
              onChange={this.changeHandler}
            />

            <input
              type="text"
              name="price"
              placeholder="Price"
              value={price}
              onChange={this.changeHandler}
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Add product</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Postform;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line to

```
changeHandler = e => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };
```

Since setState is a function it is not a property !

Comment: Please explain ***why*** this change is necessary as a more complete answer.

Comment: it works but i cant even see the diffrence? is it the ()?

Comment: Yes it is this.setState(....)  earlier it was this.setState = { [e.target.name]: e.target.value };

Comment: strange because i had that before im using prettier plugin in visual studio code and it automatically removed the () once i saved...... thanks for the help!